# how to view "log stream" log messages without truncation for ios

Tags: ios, swift, logging, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to get logs from ios simulator using `log steam` but for lengthy logs the logs are getting truncated with `<...>`

As per the document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging the live stream logs should not be truncated. I have tried with all the log levels but still logs are truncated.

This is what i am using : `log stream --style=json --predicate 'processImagePath endswith "myapp"' --level=debug`

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use **[CocoaLumberjack](https://cocoalumberjack.github.io/)**

It has lots of logging features, which can help your scenarios.